# Using std::cout makes the program return a different answer

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve this question:

> Create a program that converts Roman numbers (such as MCMLIV) to
>   Arabic numbers (1954) and back.
>
> Roman numerals are read from left to right, as you add or subtract the
>   value of each symbol.
>
> If a value is lower than the following value, it will be subtracted.
>   Otherwise it will be added.
>
> For example, we want to convert the Roman numeral MCMLIV to an Arabic
>   number:
>
> M = 1000 must be added, because the following letter C =100 is lower.
>   C = 100 must be subtracted because the following letter M =1000 is
>   greater. M = 1000 must be added, because the following letter L = 50
>   is lower.  L = 50 must be added, because the following letter I =1 is
>   lower. I = 1 must be subtracted, because the following letter V = 5 is
>   greater. V = 5 must be added, because there are no more symbols left.
>
> We can now calculate the number:  1000 - 100 + 1000 + 50 - 1 + 5 =
>   1954

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>

vector<char> alphas = {'I','V', 'X', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'M'};
vector<int> values = {1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000};


int getpos(char c){
    int index = -1;
    for (auto p: alphas){
        index += 1;
        if (p== c)
            return index;
    }
}


int main()
{

    string s; int num, ans;
    cout << "Please enter the Roman Numeral" << endl;
    cin >> s;

    int size = s.size();
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++){
        if (values[getpos(s[i-1])] > values[getpos(s[i])]){
        // If i add a std::cout statement here, it starts giving you the correct answer!
            ans += values[getpos(s[i-1])];}
        else{
            ans -= values[getpos(s[i-1])];}

}
        ans += values[getpos(s[s.size()-1])];
        cout << ans << endl;
}
```

> Input: MCMLIV
>
> Output: 1956(Incorrect)

In the next code, I make a subtle difference:

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++){
        cout << " I am comparing " << values[getpos(s[i-1])] << " and " << values[getpos(s[i])] << endl;
        if (values[getpos(s[i-1])] > values[getpos(s[i])]){
            ans += values[getpos(s[i-1])];}
        else{
            ans -= values[getpos(s[i-1])];}
```

Please enter the Roman Numeral

> Input:MCMLIV
>
> Output:
>   I am comparing 1000 and 100
>   I am comparing 100 and 1000
>   I am comparing 1000 and 50
>   I am comparing 50 and 1
>   1954 (Correct answer!)

And now the gives you the correct answer!

So how can a std::cout statement change the output of the program!?

Comment: `getpos` will not return anything if there is no such element in `alphas` that's equal to `c`. This will be undefined behaviour, if invoked, which may result in *any* kind of output.

Comment: @Fureeish There's not 'c' but 'C' is there! And why is it returning the correct answer if i am just adding a std::cout statement!?

Comment: I was talking about this `c`: `int getpos(char c)`. The name of the argument. Like I said - potential undefined behaviour may lead to anything happening. For example, the code seeming to work if you add additional `std::cout <<` calls.

Comment: @KKimash Undefined Behaviour is undefined. It can do literally anything, and there's no way to predict what it will do.

Comment: Unrelated: `s[s.size()-1]` could be `s.back()`

Comment: your "ans" variable is not initialized. So it can have any value. depend on many reason its value can be changed. One reason is actual code. So changing code anywhere may have impact on initial value of ans. Best solution is initializing ans to 0. It will work every time.

Comment: Please try to avoid `using namespace std;` because it is considered bad practice.  See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)